# Is there a way to make a Quick Edit view of a list its default view?

Tags: 2013, list-view

I have a list in SP 2013 on premise that I have created a custom view.  I want to have the default be to display it with the Quick Edit option on by default.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can do this via SharePoint Designer. Do you have access to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the steps for set default view to datasheet view.

- Go to List Settings
- Go to View Section
- Click on Your Datasheet View
- Check **"Make this the default view"** checkbox

It is set datasheet view as default view.

Reference Link : http://www.bradleyschacht.com/setting-the-default-view-on-a-sharepoint-library/

Answer (score 3):

The most straight forward way to do that is to recreate it from scratch, by going to the List tab and clicking Create View. From there click the option to start from a Datasheet view.

Configure it as you did for the existing view, then delete the old standard view.